# How to convert PostgreSQL 12 generated column to a normal column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, generated

I have a generated column in PostgreSQL 12 defined as

```
create table people (
   id bigserial primary key,
   a varchar,
   b boolean generated always as (a is not null) stored
);
```

but now i want column `b` to be settable but i don't want to lose the data already in the column, i could drop the column and recreate it but that would lose the current data.

**Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run several `ALTER TABLE` statements in a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE people ADD b_new boolean;
UPDATE people SET b_new = b;
ALTER TABLE people DROP b;
ALTER TABLE people RENAME b_new TO b;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. alter table people add  column temp_data boolean;
2. update people set temp_data=b  --(copy data from column b to temp_data)
3. Do whatever you want with column "b".
4. update people set b=temp_data   --(move data back)
5. alter table people drop column temp_data --(optional)